# .net core web app runs locally just fine but cloning code to another computer results in error

Tags: c#, docker, nginx, .net-core

I have a net core (5.0) web app that I can run locally on port `5000`. I can run this on my local ubuntu workstation using `dotnet run` or even inside a docker container and it works when I access the site via my browser at `http://localhost:5000`.

When I copy this code to my raspberry pi running ubuntu and do either `dotnet run` or running inside a container both on `5000` I get exceptions such as these when accessing the raspberry pi from the browser of my workstation on the same network using `http://[raspberry pi IP address]:5000`

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HM6I2Exxxxx", Request id "0HM6I2Exxxxx:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libsass' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibsass: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I assume I'm running into some kind of certificate issue maybe because of Kestrel?

I have an nginx instance running on the raspberry pi with a valid letsencrypt certificate which I plan to eventually use to point to my web application. Since it will handle ssl termination, I'm just trying to get my web application running on `http://localhost:5000` on the pi.

Here's part of my `Startup.cs`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .ConfigureKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
                        .UseUrls("http://*:5000");
                });

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
        
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Shared/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        ..................

        if (false)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        }

        ..................
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Website.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "Website.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Website.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Website.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
```

I build it using this command:

```
docker build --rm --pull -f "/home/webapp/website/src/Dockerfile" --label "website_test" -t "src:latest" "/home/webapp/website/src"
```

And I run the image with this command:

```
docker run --rm -d -p 5000:5000 src:latest
```

Comment: It tells you the error, you're missing a library. I can't see how this is to do with Certificates. **System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libsass'**

Comment: @JeremyThompson doh! Not sure why I glossed over that bit. It appears I am running into issues since my pi is 32 bit.

SharpScss depends on the native runtime libsass. This runtime is compiled for the following platform/runtime:

    win-x86
    win-x64
    linux-x64
    osx-x64

Comment: I suggest you work the error. The error is telling you you're missing a library. Figure out whether it is there and if not how it is supposed to get there, e.g. the deployment process, and make sure that process is functioning, etc. It seems bizarre to me that you are jumping to conclusions about certificates and platform bits with the information that you have..